# Can we compare distributions in a subsampled Kolmogorov Smirnov test?

Tags: hypothesis-testing, distributions, kolmogorov-smirnov-test

(stats newbie here)

The highlighted answer to [Can you compare p-values of Kolmogorov Smirnov tests of normality of two variables to say which is more normal?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/17173/can-you-compare-p-values-of-kolmogorov-smirnov-tests-of-normality-of-two-variabl) refers to a paper* that says that when the null hypothesis is **true**, then the p-value is a random variable, i.e. a p-value of 0.9 is just as likely as 0.1.

For my data set (wind speeds, 72 data points), I wanted to find the distribution that fit my data best and so ran the Kolmogorov Smirnov test for a number of distributions. Here I will just mention the Normal and Weibull. I find that the null hypothesis is **not rejected** for both and that p = 0.79 for Normal and p = 0.69 for Weibull.

To test out the suggestion from the answer referred to above I then randomly sampled the data set (50 samples) and ran the Kolmogorov Smirnov Test 1000 times. I find that the normal p-value > weibull p-value ~55% of the time.

So this seems to say to me that **yes**, we cannot take the "magnitude" of a p-value seriously in this case. All we can do is say **neither** normal nor weibull are rejected, therefore we must determine a better distribution another way.

But could there be a case made for a situation in which under repeated subsampled runs the p-value for one distribution was always (e.g. 99%) larger than another? e.g. if normal p was > weibull p 99% of the time.

Thank you in advance. I have been looking at a lot of similar questions today but I really wanted to try to argue this out and understand this properly...

*Murdock, D, Tsai, Y, and Adcock, J (2008) *P-Values are Random
Variables*. The American Statistician. (62) 242-245.